# Removing consecutive duplicate characters

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to remove consecutive duplicate characters from the string. So the input of `aabbcde` should output as `cde`.

I wrote the following code, but I am getting the incorrect output. I could not understand why.

```js
var a = "aabbccddeef"
var ncopy = a;

let leftPointer = 0;
let rightPointer = 1;

let posList = [];

while (true) {
  if (a[leftPointer] == a[rightPointer]) {
    ncopy = ncopy.replace(a.slice(leftPointer, rightPointer + 1), '')
    leftPointer += 2
    rightPointer = leftPointer + 1;
    if (leftPointer >= a.length || rightPointer >= a.length) {
      break;
    }
  } else {
    leftPointer++;
    rightPointer++;
  }
}

console.log(ncopy);
```

Comment: You have 3 consecutive `y` characters, why should they all be removed?

Comment: @Barmar When you remove 4 d's then it becomes 4 y's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a following recursive function:

```js
const input = 'aabbccddeeffg';


function getResult(str) {

  const newStr = str.match(/(.)\1*/g).filter(str => !((str.length % 2 === 0) && (str.split('').every((char,i,arr) => char === arr[0])))).join('');

  return newStr === str ? newStr : getResult(newStr)

}

const result = getResult(input);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This snippet is producing an error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'str.match(/(.)\1*/g).filter')` for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple regex:

```
'aabbbcde'.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '')
```

Result:

```
'cde'
```

Snippet:

```js
var a = 'aabbbcde';
var result = a.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If the choice regexp then obviously this is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

```
'aabbccde'
  .split('')
  .reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      if (acc.indexOf(cur) !== -1) {
        return acc.slice(acc.length);
      }
      return [...acc, cur];
    }
  )
  .join('')
```